# How to inject a custom filter in AngularJS 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component into which I would like to inject a custom filter, `status`.

My component looks like this:

```
function ClaimsListController(dpClaimsListService) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.claims = null;
    ctrl.searchCriterion = null;

    ctrl.loadClaimsList = function() {
        dpClaimsListService.getUploadRequests(1,
            function (claims) {
                ctrl.claims = claims.data;                
            },
            function () {
                // error handling? display message to user?
            });
    }

    ctrl.loadClaimsList(1);
}

angular.module('dpApp').component('dpClaimsListService', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/dp-claims-list.tmpl.html',
    controller: ClaimsListController
});
```

I can't work out how to inject my `status` filter into my component in a DI-minificaiton safe way. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you can inject your service in the controller

Comment: You've implied that `status` is both a service and a filter.. which one is it?

Comment: @Ankh yes sorry about that. `status` is a filter, post amended.

Comment: Your component also has a confusing name, `dpClaimsListService`, it looks like you have an actual service with the same name injected into your controller? You should be able to inject services into your controller like any, except you'll be injecting `$filter` to use `$filter('status')(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I don't need to inject the filter; I neglected to include it in my bundle.